# How can i use divs properly

Tags: html, css

Hello i was trying to create a navbar and a red box below it. But red box came in the navbar .
I used css and html only . I have also provided the before and after of the outcomes
[image: Second]
[image: first]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bar">
   <img src="background.png" class="pic">
   <nav>
     <ul class="navlist">
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Search</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Browse</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Tags</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Filter</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Dev</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="signin"><a href="#" class='sign'>Sign In</a</div>
 </div>
 <div class="introbox">abcd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the closing bracket of the anchor element
`<div class="signin"><a href="#" class='sign'>Sign In</a></div>`